# CD4051 noise measurement

Tags: noise, measurement

I am using a [CD4051B](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4051b.pdf?ts=1651652672390&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCD4051B) for multiplexing 8 inputs into one according to 3 control bit A, B, C.

Below is my schematic:

[image]

My problem is :
The input of the MUX (in_mux) is quiet disturbed on my PCB board when the product is ON. When the MUX read on the in_mux input, there is a 100 Hz noise (we should read a DC signal around 100 mV without variation).
Here you can see a screen shot of the input measurement:

[image]

The 3 control bits are well controlled by the microcontroler. I have got a PFC on my PCB board which can maybe disturb the MUX but I don't understand what happens.

I have removed the R1 resistor, here is the signal:

[image]

Purple : input MUX,
Orange : Output MUX

We notice that the MUX reads the input correctly and sends the value to the output. Why do I have a charge of the capacitor only when the MUX read this input value?

Is it possible to have one of the other inputs which leaks current on this input?

When I put a low input impedance by reducing the value of the resitor, the noise is reduced but I can't understand why.

Thank you for four help.

Comment: What is connected to the mux output? It looks like it is sending current into the mux output, which charges the cap when the mux connects input and output. If it is a micro ADC input, did you forget to remove the pullup?

Comment: Yes it is a microcontroler ADC input. For this, I separate the output to be sure that there is nothing which can charge the cap when the mux connects input and output.

Comment: OK, so you confirm the cap is charging when the corresponding input is selected by the mux, and discharging when it is not? Even with the output connected to nothing? Looking at the scope, with i=C*dv/dt, the discharge current looks like about 66nA, which is coherent with 0.5V over the 10MOhm scope probe resistance. So the down slope seems due to the scope probe discharging the cap, nothing to see here.

Comment: The up slope is about 200mV in 50ms, which corresponds to 400nA on a 100nF cap. CD4051 specs 300nA leakage current maximum. Hmmm... Can you try heating or cooling the chip, I mean just the chip and nothing else, for example put a drop of alcohol on it and let it evaporate to cool it, or stick a finger on it without touching the pins. Hotter should increase leakage, cooler should decrease it, so you should see a change in upwards slope on your scope.

Comment: Decoupling capacitor ok, should also use a load resistor ~ 2..10 kOhm, feedthrough (all unused inputs to ground)?

Comment: I agree, the leakage current should not charge the capacitor at this value... I have tried to separate all the other input which arrive in the MUX and I see that one of the input affect the noise read on the input disturbed. By putting a RC to the other input disturbed, I have no more noise to the first input which were disturbed. I conclude that inside the MUX, with noise in one of the input, it can disturb other input (parasit capacitors in the Cmos  gate insique the MUX).

Comment: Yes all inputs of the MUX have an impedance (resistor + capacitor) on my pcb.

Comment: NB: can't see on the picture if supply pins are ok. Note that there are three pins for the power supplies; VDD, VEE, and VSS. Are they all connected? And INH?

Comment: This can also be useful https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/multiplexer-breakout-hookup-guide/all

Comment: If the problem is switch leakage current, it should only matter if source impedance is very high. So it will show up when no source is connected to the input, but if you connect a source with a low enough impedance, it'll be OK. For 200nA to cause a less than 1LSB change on a 12 bit DAC on 5V, you'd need less than 6kOhm source impedance. Otherwise, you can use a lower leakage switch, like [DG508](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/661228.pdf) which has 2nA leakage, BUT ONLY AT 25°C (beware).

Comment: Yes the schematic is only a diagram and not the real schema. The MUX is well supplied, it works well on other project.

Comment: You are right, with a low impedance, the problem is attenuated. I solved the problem by putting a RC filter to the input which disturb the MUX. All the input and output of the MUX is suitable.